# Muliple Items in ADO Query

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I wanted to query multiple selective tickets on ADO in a single line any suggestions
I am expecting to query in a single line like 2810, 2910

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use operator 'In' to query multiple items
[image]